# MS Access 2007 Form OnLoad Event Not Triggering

Tags: events, ms-access, vba, onload-event

Two forms in an A2007 app have stopped triggering their **OnLoad** events after the OnOpen event. The events have been working for years, and I can't determine why the OnLoad event isn't running now.

Instead, clicking on **any** control on the forms triggers the OnLoad event - including the window's Close button.

The forms are unbound, with subforms that are filtered by a common function called in the OnLoad event. There are many other forms like this, which are still working OK.

I have checked that **the event is still linked to the code** by clicking on the ellipsis in Properties next to the event ([Event Procedure]), which takes me correctly to the code.

Have decompiled/recompiled. Checked References. Imported to a new db.

Tried adding a RecordSource (SELECT anyField FROM anyTable LIMIT 1), which didn't work, and then I found a **work-around**, by adding Me.RecordSource=Me.RecordSource as the last line in the OnOpen event - which *does* then trigger the OnLoad event.

This is the first time in almost 20 yrs of Access development that I've come across this, and as I get very nervous whenever Access 'misbehaves', I'd really like to find the problem. Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: very strange indeed. every other instance i can find of this problem on the internet mentions lost links to the event.. but you have already checked that. probably won't work but have you cleared the event link, deleted sub definition (copy it somewhere else), and then recreate the event by hitting the ellipsis in the On Load property, and pasting in the definition? another (albeit terrible) work around is to call the Load sub as the last line from the Open sub.

Comment: also, done a compact and repair?

Comment: I can't think of why this may be happening, but from working with unbound forms, there isn't a great deal of difference between the "Open" & "Load" events, I know it doesn't solve the issue but can you not move the code in to the "Open" event?

Comment: @MattDonnan There is a great deal of difference. You cannot reference controls in the Open event.

Comment: Do the forms that don't work have any ocx controls? Any odd controls? Have you updated Windows or Office? Have the order of references changed?

Comment: Not an answer, but interesting: http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/980285-access-fails-run-load-event-load-untill-user-clicks-why.html. Would it be worth copying the form and deleting any suspect controls as a test? Also interesting, though probably not relevant to you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/3689986b-db8f-4cda-8f00-ce3253839052

Comment: Had a similar problem, taken a lot of hours before I solved it. OnLoad event not triggering in spite of similar codes to other programs. I had realized you need to code the OnLoad event first before coding the OnCurrent event. Kinda illogical move but it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a form I was developing however I didn't have any code in the Open event but suddenly my Load event code stopped running when opening the form.

Adding the "Me.RecordSource = Me.RecordSource" code in the Open event then resolved the issue?

I know this isn't an answer but it does prove that Max's code couldn't have been hung up in the Open event.

The only other significant information is that I am developing this on two PCs, one with Access 2007 and one with 2010 but I don't recall if the Load event stopped running after I moved the code back to the Access 2007 PC.

Answer (score 0):

Had a problem with the same symptoms in MS Access 2016.
But Adding "Me.RecordSource = Me.RecordSource" did not help me, it made it worse.

After successlessly trying the other suggested solutions with building the form completely new from scratch, I built it up again and after every step checking whether it still functioned.

It came out that access cannot handle calling a function (with return value) as default for an optional parameter. (This applicates to all procedures defined in the forms module)

As I am fairly new to VBA and Access development this may be a beginners mistake, but maybe it helps someone to post it here.